# Is it possible to create a windows 10 Snackbar application?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, user-experience

I would like to create an application that utilizes snackbar like windowing in windows 10, i searched around google but found nothing, i might using the wrong search term, so how do i go about this?

Sample:
[image]

Comment: So you want to create a program that appears in the taskbar, and when user click on a region in taskbar it will popup the UI of the program?

Comment: Yeah something like that, but native, just like the one i've shown.

Comment: What do you mean by "native"? The UI style is the same with the Windows OS or what?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I researched, you cannot create a region like Date and Time on taskbar, but you CAN create a system tray icon just like this:

[image]

You can develop it with WPF and NuGet package Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf. Read more at http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon.